# Add column in view with days count inbetween two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one sql table name StudentInfo
where data are as

```
StudentID   Age startDate   EndDate

1       14  5/05/2013   7/05/2013   
4       17  4/04/2012   8/10/2012
```

i want to create a view for this table in which add one more column 
with name total days which shows the days between StartDat and Enddate .
like i want result of view as

```
StudentID   Age startDate   EndDate     TotalDays

1       14  5/05/2013   7/05/2013   3
4       17  4/04/2012   8/04/2012   5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `datediff` to calculate the number of days:

```
create view dbo.vw_StudentInfo
as
select  StudentID
,       Age
,       StartDate
,       EndDarte
,       datediff(day, StartDate, EndDate) as TotalDays
from    dbo.StudentInfo
```